# Homeomorphism between function spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory

I was reading [proof for $Map(X\times Y, Z) \cong Map(X, Map(Y,Z))$](http://people.brandeis.edu/~igusa/Math121b/121bHomotopy.pdf). As a corollary 7.14, pg4, author wrote,

> Corollary: $Map_0(X \wedge Y, Z) \cong Map_0(X, Map_0(Y,Z))$ in Top$^0$.

**How does this follow?**

---

**Suppose I want to past on this result to the category of [CGWH](https://neil-strickland.staff.shef.ac.uk/courses/homotopy/cgwh.pdf) spaces. How does one do this rigorously?**

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that $Map_0(X \wedge Y, Z) \cong Map_0(X, Map_0(Y,Z))$ is a direct corollary of $Map(X\times Y, Z) \cong Map(X, Map(Y,Z))$. You can easily verify that there is a canonical bijection, but to show that it is a homeomorphism needs extra arguments.

See for example Section 2.4 of

tom Dieck, Tammo. Algebraic topology. Vol. 8. European Mathematical Society, 2008.

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul. I understand the proof now but this also has to be done separately for CGWH spaces? Is there anything different in that case? It seems to me that it works fine, but I'd be interested to see a simple proof.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but I believe that you are entering an area not completely treated in the literature. I am convinced that there is a version in the category of ´pointed CGWH spaces if you use an appropriate definition of $X \wedge Y$ (probably $X \wedge_k  Y = k(X \wedge Y)$), but the proof will be similar to Ronnie Brown's proof of the "ordinary" exponential law for unpointed spaces. An essential ingredient should be that the evaluation map $kMap_0(X,Y) \wedge_k X \to Y$ is continuous. See again tom Dieck.

Comment: @paulfrost You certainly can prove it as a corollary as I suggest below. I'm too lazy to write out all the details but here the author does so on the first page: https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1996-124-04/S0002-9939-96-03065-1/S0002-9939-96-03065-1.pdf

Comment: @leibnewtz We agree that there exists an exponential heomeomorphism in the pointed category and that the existence of a bijection is a corollary of the unpointed case. The paper which you quote only proves  the bijection-part, the topologies on the $hom$-sets are out of focus. By the way, the existence of a right adjoint for the smash product functor is not proved as a corollary of the unpointed exponential theorem.

Comment: @leibnewtz As you said in your answer, $Map_0(X \wedge Y, Z)$ can be identified with a subspace $S$ of $Map(X \times Y, Z)$, similarly $Map_0(X, Map_0(Y, Z)$ with a subspace $S'$ of $Map(X, Map(Y, Z))$. The exponential map throws $S$ homeomorphically onto $S'$. I moreover see that the quotient map $p : X \times Y \to X \wedge Y$ induces a *continuous* bijection $p^\ast : Map_0(X \wedge Y, Z) \to S$. Probably it can be shown that $p^\ast$ is an open map, but I do not see that this would be a direct corollary of the unpointed result.

Comment: @paulfrost Obviously there are some basic topological issues to resolve. I think the problem here is that what it means to be a corollary is kind of subjective

Comment: @leibnewtz I absolutely agree!

Answer (score 0):

Since pointed maps $X \wedge Y \to Z$ are precisely pointed maps $X \times Y \to Z$ that send the wedge sum of $X$ and $Y$ to the base point in $Z$, by the adjunction we know that such maps correspond to certain maps $X \to Maps(Y,Z)$. Can you figure out which these are?

These adjunctions work for all reasonable spaces.

Comment: You only have a set bijection here ? Can you deduce a homeomorphism directly?

Comment: That the map is continuous follows from the fact that it's the restriction of a continuous map, and likewise for its inverse

Comment: You cannot really restrict the map can you? We are mapping into different spaces.

Comment: You can, since $Maps_0(Y,Z) \subseteq Maps(Y,Z)$. As a set, $Maps_0(Y,Z)$ is just the set of maps $Y \to Z$ that take distinguished point to distinguished point. After restriction the map lands in the former space